# Why is my content grid area longer when used on wide media?

Tags: html, css

Disclaimer: I'm not an experienced web designer.

I've been playing around with grid and have this mock up for different screen sizes but I cannot understand why the div content area grows so much taller than the nested panelwrap grid inside it? (Im testing on Chrome).

According to chrome inspector the size only grows when the content area is over 647px wide.

I just want to understand why the space occurs?

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.sidebar2 {
  grid-area: sidebar2;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "sidebar" "content" "sidebar2" "footer"
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 20% auto;
    grid-template-areas: "header   header" "sidebar  content" "sidebar2 sidebar2" "footer   footer";
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 120px auto 120px;
    grid-template-areas: "header  header  header" "sidebar content sidebar2" "footer  footer  footer";
    max-width: auto;
  }
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #999;
}

.sidebar2 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #444;
}

.panelwrap {
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

.panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.tall-panel {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.wide-panel {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box header">Header</div>
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box sidebar2">Sidebar 2</div>
  <div class="box content">Content
    <div class="panelwrap">
      <div class="panel">Panel A</div>
      <div class="panel">Panel B</div>
      <div class="panel tall-panel">Panel C</div>
      <div class="panel">Panel D</div>
      <div class="panel">Panel E</div>
      <div class="panel">Panel F</div>
      <div class="panel tall-panel">Panel G</div>
      <div class="panel tall-panel">Panel H</div>
      <div class="panel">Panel I</div>
      <div class="panel">Panel J</div>
      <div class="panel wide-panel">Panel K</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Which space specifically are you talking about? It seems that on all 3 possible media queries there's a blank space. But I suppose it's due to the grid-item being larger than the specified size you directed (except in the largest media-query, there the space is simply vacant since the last grid-item is not large enough to fill it). Since the grid-item is larger than the remaining row space, it is moved to the next row. It could be easier to do a `grid-template-areas` again in `.panelwrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may have been an issue with the Chrome browser at the time (not sure of version I used but I am now on Version 63.0.3239.84).

I've just tested the same identical code and the content area now matches the items within it.  Previously when the display was > 647px wide the content area was much longer than the panels within.

[image: For clarity screenshot, now fixed]